# Deploying JApplet from HTML

Tags: html, japplet

I tried to follow JavaTutorial step by step but i didnt get it... help me figure out this exemple:

my JApplet:

```
package test;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class Test extends JApplet {
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

and my HTML:

```
<applet archive="ofek.jar" class="test.Test" width="100" height="100">
</applet>
```

and I have the ofek.jar file in the same dir as the HTML file

what else needed to be done? cause when i double click the HTML file i see a white blank screen (was expecting Hello World string...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it work the way you wanted when you ran it on its own, before trying to stick it in a webpage? Because System.out.println() prints to the console so check to see if something printed out there. Try using

```
public void start(){
  try{
     SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable(){
       public void run(){
         JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Hello World");
         add(lbl);
       }
     });
  }
  catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e);
  }
}
```

in place of your current start() method

Comment: thing is putting it on the webpage is all im struggling with

Comment: what browser are you using, does your applet work on its on, is it printing to the console?

Comment: google chrome... I tried to override paint(Graphics g) so it draw some oval but still nothing heppends i dont know why.. I also tried bringing .class and .java files to the same dir and changed the html and still i got nothing :(

Comment: its working for me (sort of)...going through standard debugging here: your html has no errors? Neither does the rest of your java? Did you try running it as its own .java file, not pulling it in from the jar? (i think that's what you said) Is chrome giving you an error message of any kind?

Comment: The code in `start()` should instead be in the (called once only) `init()` method.